# I want to save the registration infos in dataset,but didn't work this code for making a new row here:

Tags: c#, database, validation, updating

I want to save a new account by clicking the button.When I want to try the login function is row 1 (row id) was null. The `nextRegisteredAccount` is 1 by default. Here is my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Person_Information newTable = new Person_Information();
    Person_Information.UsersRow newRow = newTable.Users.NewUsersRow();
    newRow.Id = FoodTracker.Properties.Settings.Default.nextRegisteredAccountID;
    newRow.Username = textBox1.Text;
    newRow.Passworld = textBox2.Text;
    newRow.RealName = textBox4.Text;
    newRow.Weight = int.Parse(textBox5.Text);
    newRow.Height = int.Parse(textBox6.Text);
    newTable.Users.Rows.Add(newRow);
    FoodTracker.Properties.Settings.Default.nextRegisteredAccountID++;
    FoodTracker.Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

It didn't save the new row. Is something missing?

Comment: You will need to provide more information, from your example I don't see any dbcontext or database connection. Are you trying to save this to the database or just insert an additional row in your table?

Comment: I have a dataSet called Person_Information,here i have a table called Users,which has 6 columns.I want to insert a new row to this table,with the informations from textboxes,and than save this table.I want to keep registered users  for next starts.

Comment: If you are looking for help on homework assignments you probably won't get much help here. If you are trying to connect with databases in this manner you should look into using an ORM such as Entity Framework. But if you are doing this as a school assignment using raw SQL statements is probably your best bet.